# C++ Getters/Setters, would this be a good approach?

Tags: c++, getter-setter

So the original Getter/Setter is something like the following style (with added additional casts, also keep in mind I'm using ints and floats in those examples, could be more complex data)

```
struct JustAnInteger {
    int i;
};

class Foo {
private:
    int _bar;

public:
    Foo(int bar) : _bar(bar) {}

    void setBar(int bar) { _bar = bar; }

    int getBar() const {
        return _bar;
    }
    double getBarDouble() const {
        return (double)_bar;
    }
    std::string getBarString() const {
        return std::to_string(_bar);
    }
    JustAnInteger getBarJustAnInteger() const {
        return JustAnInteger{ _bar };
    }
};
```

Would be changing to the following way a good or a bad idea?

```
class Foo {
private:
    int _bar;
public:
    Foo(int bar) : _bar(bar) {}

    void bar(int bar) { _bar = bar; }

    template <class T = int> //int is the original type
    T bar() const;
    template <>
    int bar<int>() const {
        return _bar;
    }
    template <> double bar<double>() const {
        return (double)_bar;
    }
    template <> std::string bar<std::string>() const {
        return std::to_string(_bar);
    }
    template <> JustAnInteger bar<JustAnInteger>() const {
        return JustAnInteger{ bar() };
    }
};
```

This way would allow to easily change the type of _bar, for example to a float

```
class Foo{
private:
    float _bar;
public:
    Foo(int bar) : _bar((float)bar) {}
    Foo(float bar) : _bar(bar) {}

    void bar(int bar) { _bar = (float)bar; }
    void bar(float bar) { _bar = bar; }

    template <class T = int>
    T bar() const;
    template <> int bar<int>() const {
        return (int)_bar;
    }
    template <> double bar<double>() const {
        return (double)_bar;
    }
    template <> std::string bar<std::string>() const {
        return std::to_string(_bar);
    }
    template <> JustAnInteger bar<JustAnInteger>() const {
        return JustAnInteger{ bar() };
    }
};
```

And shouldn't break other parts of the code

```
Foo foo(2);
foo.bar(2.999f); //Now we can use floats!
int a = foo.bar(); //Still an int
double b = foo.bar<double>(); //can keep using it, and we gain precision
```

Comment: Take a step back and ask yourself if it [makes sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for an object's interface to implement conversion between numeric types. Isn't numeric conversion a generic concept that might apply to a wide variety of situations? Thus, should the caller take care of it (perhaps, if the conversions are complex, with the assistance of third party functions)?

Comment: Side note: `void setBar(int bar) { _bar = bar; }` allows anyone to set any value. Add in the getter and the variable is `public` in all but name. What you do get out of this, and it is worthwhile, is a good place to hang a breakpoint to help find out who is writing bad values. Accessor functions are at their best when they provide some sort of value-add, like protecting the object from invalid entry.

Comment: @TypeIA I used int/floats for simplicity, imagine that now I want to change my `int _bar;` to `JustAnInteger _bar;` instead, the original getter would still work (with little modifications on the class and zero modifications outside)

Comment: Accessor functions for breakpoints are old, outdated ideas that recent debuggers make unnecessary. You can break on the memory address.

Comment: Note that memory breakpoints find *all* changes to the memory, including ones through wild pointers, dangling references, buffer overflows, etc.  It may at times be useful to set a memory breakpoint and exclude the designated setter function that is supposed to be responsible, to find if unintended accesses are occurring.

Comment: @user1090694 OK, but my point still stands. Extensive conversions are a different [_concern_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) than what the class is actually meant to do. You could quite easily implement explicit or implicit conversions between `JustAnInteger` and `int` (via constructors and type conversion operators) and then these conversions become available to _any_ code that might need to make them, not just code using the bloated `Foo` interface.

Comment: Getters and setters are a [code smell](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html) (also [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/)).